# Use HttpRunner to run the command "hrp run" and report an error

Tags: python

### Run the following command:

```
$ hrp run demo/testcases/demo_requests.yml demo/testcases/demo_ref_testcase.yml
```

### error:

```sh
    11:01AM INF Set log to color console other than JSON format.
    11:01AM ??? Set log level
    11:01AM INF [init] SetFailfast failfast=true
    11:01AM INF [init] SetSaveTests saveTests=false
    11:01AM INF [init] SetgenHTMLReport genHTMLReport=true
    11:01AM INF [init] SetRequestsLogOn
    11:01AM INF load file path=demo/testcases/demo_requests.yml
    11:01AM INF load file path=demo/testcases/demo_ref_testcase.yml
    11:01AM INF load file path=~/demo/testcases/demo_requests.yml
    11:01AM INF load testcases successfully count=2
    11:01AM INF ensure python3 venv packages=["funppy==v0.4.3"] python=~/.hrp/venv/bin/python
    11:01AM INF installing python package package=funppy==v0.4.3
    11:01AM ERR init plugin failed: ~/demo/debugtalk.py error="ensure python venv failed: pip install funppy==v0.4.3 failed: pip install package failed: exit status 1"
    11:01AM ERR [Run] init session runner failed error="init plugin failed: ensure python venv failed: pip install funppy==v0.4.3 failed: pip install package failed: exit status 1"
```

### I have installed python3-venv and funppy:

1. Installed python3-venv

   dpkg -l|grep python3-venv
   ii  python3-venv                                                     3.6.7-1~18.04                                   amd64        pyvenv-3 binary for python3 (default python3 version)
2. Installed funppy

   pip list | grep funppy
   funppy                         0.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this httprunner test tool, it captures all your test activities to Google Analytics and send error logs to a sentry.io database

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32368423)